# Will selecting the firestore multi-region speed up access from regions around the world?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Currently, there are only two multi-regions of firestore, but if you select these, will access from other regions be quicker?

When I accessed an app that selected the Tokyo region from Germany, I was surprised at the slow speed of the firestore.[image]

Comment: Did you deploy your project in multiregion in the end? If so, did you use any event functions on it? I deployed to multi-region Eur3 and cannot seem to get functions to depploy.

Answer (score -1):

> Will access from other regions be quicker?

Before you use Cloud Firestore, you must choose a *location* for your database. To reduce latency and increase availability, store your data close to the users and services that need it. Select a [regional location](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations#location-r) for lower costs, for lower write latency if your application is sensitive to latency, or for co-location with other GCP resources.

> Will selecting the Firestore multi-region speed up access from regions around the world?

[Multi-region Locations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations#location-r) locations can withstand the loss of entire regions and maintain availability without losing data. Global apps can take advantage of the Multiregion deployment of the Firestore. Having multiple servers distributed worldwide reduces the latency for the end-users, increases performance, and data will not be lost in the event of a catastrophic event in a single datacenter region.

Note:

> For choosing the [database location](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#database_location), it is important to know what are the best practices that you can follow. Having been said that, when you create your database instance, select the database location closest to your users and compute resources. Far-reaching network hops are more error-prone and increase query latency.